# How to make the mapview get from current location?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mapview, gmsmapview

As title, how to make the mapview zoom into the current location? By the way, I can get the current Log and Lon in getLocation(). Just don't know how to implement into the map. Thanks in advance someone who can help me.. I'm new to the android studio. This problem have make me confuse few day already.

```
package com.example.edward.neweventmanagementsystem;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class StaffAttendanceCheckIn extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private TextView mtxtTime, mtxtDate, txtDisplayName;
    private Spinner eventSpinner;

    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;
    TextView textLocation;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String latitude,longitude;
    MapView mapview;
    private GoogleMap map;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_staff_attendance_check_in);

        mtxtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentDate);
        mtxtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentTime);
        txtDisplayName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplayName);
        eventSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.eventSpinner);
        mapview = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        mapview.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String currentDate = date.format(new Date());

        SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String currentTime = time.format(new Date());

        mtxtDate.setText(currentDate);
        mtxtTime.setText(currentTime);

        FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() ;
        txtDisplayName.setText(currentFirebaseUser.getDisplayName());

        /**
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("EventName");

        System.out.println("Test Script: " + myRef); */

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        textLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.location);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();

        } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            getLocation();
        }

    }

//    @Override
//    public void onClick(View view) {
//
//    }

    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(com.example.edward.neweventmanagementsystem.StaffAttendanceCheckIn.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (com.example.edward.neweventmanagementsystem.StaffAttendanceCheckIn.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(com.example.edward.neweventmanagementsystem.StaffAttendanceCheckIn.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);

        } else {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            Location location1 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            Location location2 = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager. PASSIVE_PROVIDER);

            if (location != null) {
                double latti = location.getLatitude();
                double longi = location.getLongitude();

                latitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

                textLocation.setText("Lat = " + latitude + "\n" + "Lon = " + longitude);

                float ZOOM_MAP = 17.0f;
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                CameraUpdate myLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, ZOOM_MAP);
                map.animateCamera(myLocation);


//                CameraUpdate myLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, ZOOM_MAP);
//                System.out.println("Test Script" + myLocation);
//                map.animateCamera(myLocation);


            } else  if (location1 != null) {
                double latti = location1.getLatitude();
                double longi = location1.getLongitude();
                latitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

                textLocation.setText("Lat = " + latitude + "\n" + "Lon = " + longitude);

            } else  if (location2 != null) {
                double latti = location2.getLatitude();
                double longi = location2.getLongitude();
                latitude = String.valueOf(latti);
                longitude = String.valueOf(longi);

                textLocation.setText("Lat = " + latitude + "\n" + "Lon = " + longitude);

            }else{

                Toast.makeText(this,"Unble to Trace your location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }

    protected void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Please Turn ON your GPS Connection")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        mapview.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory(){
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapview.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mapview.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mapview.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapview.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy you just need to do like:

```
CameraUpdate myLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(yourLatLng, ZOOM_MAP);
mMap.animateCamera(myLocation);
```

ZOOM_MAP its float

Update ----

```
    mapview.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    CameraUpdate myLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(yourLatLng, ZOOM_MAP);
                    googleMap.animateCamera(myLocation);
                }
            });
```

Comment: But where should I put it? I try put in getLocation but can't

Comment: why you can`t? it must be after that you will get LatLng

Comment: you need to get real GoogleMap object